# FATAL EXCEPTION: main,able to start activity ComponentInfo,java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm a beginner programmer and I've started a web crawler application from a weather site. When I run the application while the first two cities of each Activity are working normally, the others stops the application with the following message: "Current_Weather was interrupted. Please help me if there is a solution to my problem.

**Error Message :**

```
06-24 16:03:04.805 18004-18004/com.example.junior_marg.current_weather E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                         Process: com.example.junior_marg.current_weather, PID: 18004
                                                                                         java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.junior_marg.current_weather/com.example.junior_marg.current_weather.Main14Activity}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2927)
                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2988)
                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1631)
                                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
                                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
                                                                                          Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
                                                                                             at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
                                                                                             at com.example.junior_marg.current_weather.Main14Activity.onCreate(Main14Activity.java:94)
                                                                                             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6942)
                                                                                             at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126)
                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2880)
                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2988) 
                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1631) 
                                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682) 
                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520) 
                                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

**Java Code:**

```
package com.example.junior_marg.current_weather;

import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Main14Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView mTextView_33;
    TextView mTextView_34;
    TextView mTextView_35;
    TextView mTextView_36;
    TextView mTextView_37;
    TextView mTextView_38;
    TextView mTextView_39;
    TextView mTextView_40;
    TextView mTextView_41;
    TextView mTextView_42;
    TextView mTextView_43;
    TextView mTextView_44;
    TextView mTextView_45;
    TextView mTextView_46;
    TextView mTextView_47;
    TextView mTextView_48;

    String therm_3;
    String ygrasia_3;
    String simdrosou_3;
    String anemos_3;
    String varom_3;
    String simerinosy_3;
    String ragd_3;
    String trexkak_3;
    String miniaiosy_3;
    String ethsiosy_3;
    String aisthpsix_3;
    String yperithriakt_3;
    String deiktisdis_3;
    String hliakiakt_3;
    String anatoli_3;
    String disi_3;

    String url;
    Document doc;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main14);

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        mTextView_33 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview77);
        mTextView_34 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview79);
        mTextView_35 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview81);
        mTextView_36 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview83);
        mTextView_37 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview85);
        mTextView_38 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview87);
        mTextView_39 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview89);
        mTextView_40 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview91);
        mTextView_41 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview93);
        mTextView_42 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview95);
        mTextView_43 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview97);
        mTextView_44 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview99);
        mTextView_45 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview101);
        mTextView_46 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview103);
        mTextView_47 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview105);
        mTextView_48 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview107);

        doc = null;
        url = "http://penteli.meteo.gr/stations/larissa/";

        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Element table_33 = doc.select("table").get(0);
        Elements rows_33 = table_33.select("tr");

        Element row_33 = rows_33.get(5);
        Elements cols_33 = row_33.select("td");

        therm_3 =  cols_33.get(1).text() ;

        mTextView_33.setText(therm_3);

        Element row_34 = rows_33.get(6);
        Elements cols_34= row_34.select("td");

        ygrasia_3 =  cols_34.get(1).text() ;

        mTextView_34.setText(ygrasia_3);

        Element row_35 = rows_33.get(7);
        Elements cols_35 = row_35.select("td");

        simdrosou_3 =  cols_35.get(1).text() ;

        mTextView_35.setText(simdrosou_3);

        Element row_36 = rows_33.get(8);
        Elements cols_36 = row_36.select("td");

        anemos_3 =  cols_36.get(1).text() ;

        mTextView_36.setText(anemos_3);

        Element row_37 = rows_33.get(9);
        Elements cols_37 = row_37.select("td");

        varom_3 =  cols_37.get(1).text() ;

        mTextView_37.setText(varom_3);

        Element row_38 = rows_33.get(10);
        Elements cols_38 = row_38.select("td");

        simerinosy_3 =  cols_38.get(1).text() ;

        mTextView_38.setText(simerinosy_3);

        Element row_39 = rows_33.get(11);
        Elements cols_39 = row_39.select("td");

        ragd_3 =  cols_39.get(1).text() ;

        mTextView_39.setText(ragd_3);

        Element row_40 = rows_33.get(12);
        Elements cols_40 = row_40.select("td");

        trexkak_3 =  cols_40.get(1).text() ;

        mTextView_40.setText(trexkak_3);

        Element row_41 = rows_33.get(13);
        Elements cols_41 = row_41.select("td");

        miniaiosy_3 =  cols_41.get(1).text() ;

        mTextView_41.setText(miniaiosy_3);

        Element row_42 = rows_33.get(14);
        Elements cols_42 = row_42.select("td");

        ethsiosy_3 =  cols_42.get(1).text() ;

        mTextView_42.setText(ethsiosy_3);

        Element row_43 = rows_33.get(15);
        Elements cols_43 = row_43.select("td");

        aisthpsix_3 =  cols_43.get(1).text() ;

        mTextView_43.setText(aisthpsix_3);

        Element row_44 = rows_33.get(16);
        Elements cols_44 = row_44.select("td");

        yperithriakt_3 =  cols_44.get(1).text() ;

        mTextView_44.setText(yperithriakt_3);

        Element row_45 = rows_33.get(17);
        Elements cols_45 = row_45.select("td");

        deiktisdis_3 =  cols_45.get(1).text() ;

        mTextView_45.setText(deiktisdis_3);

        Element row_46 = rows_33.get(18);
        Elements cols_46 = row_46.select("td");

        hliakiakt_3 =  cols_46.get(1).text() ;

        mTextView_46.setText(hliakiakt_3);

        Element row_47 = rows_33.get(19);
        Elements cols_47 = row_47.select("td");

        anatoli_3 =  cols_47.get(1).text() ;

        mTextView_47.setText(anatoli_3);

        Element row_48 = rows_33.get(20);
        Elements cols_48 = row_48.select("td");

        disi_3 =  cols_48.get(1).text() ;

        mTextView_48.setText(disi_3);
    }
}
```

**XML Code :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.junior_marg.current_weather.Main14Activity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview76"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/c"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview77"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textview76"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="92dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview78"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/d"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textview76"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview79"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textview78"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textview77"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="133dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview80"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/h2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textview78"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview81"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textview80"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="77dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="63dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview82"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/i2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textview80"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview83"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textview82"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="130dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="90dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview84"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/j2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textview82"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview85"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textview84"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textview83"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="104dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview86"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/k2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textview84"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview87"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textview86"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textview85"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="63dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="11dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview88"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/l2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textview86"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview89"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textview88"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textview87"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="94dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview90"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/m2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textview88"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview91"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textview90"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textview89"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="36dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview92"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/n2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textview90"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview93"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textview92"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textview91"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="75dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview94"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/o2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textview92"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview95"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textview94"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textview93"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="85dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview96"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/p2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textview94"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview97"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textview96"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textview95"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="73dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview98"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/q2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textview96"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview99"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textview98"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textview97"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview100"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/r2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textview98"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview101"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textview100"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textview99"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="52dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview102"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/s2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textview100"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview103"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textview102"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textview101"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="45dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="11dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview104"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/t2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textview102"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview105"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textview104"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textview103"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="122dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview106"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/u2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textview104"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview107"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textview106"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textview105"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="151dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is in `therm_3 =  cols_33.get(1).text() ;`. it seems that your `cols_33` just has one element while you are trying to get it's second element. I hope your problem would be solved if you replace that line with this:
`therm_3 =  cols_33.get(0).text() ;`

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, you are the best.
The solution you gave me solved my problem and the application works normally but the matches are not right. The results have been moved to a line below, with the result the temperature appears next to the wind and so on.If there is a solution to this problem I would be grateful to you.

Comment: i think your problem is that some time you forgot that your array start from zero. for example as i saw in the page html, i think in this line : `Element row_33 = rows_33.get(5);` you are trying to get the `Temperature`. if it is true, so you are using wrong code because `Temperature` index is 4 not 5. and you should use `Element row_33 = rows_33.get(4);` to get `Temperature`.

Comment: I used the code 'Element row_33 = rows_33.get(4);' and the application stopped working, but when I tried it with code 'Element row_33 = rows_33.get(6);' the application worked and my problem was resolved.
Thank you very much for the valuable help and I am thankful for it. If you know why it worked with index 6 and not with 4 it would help me a lot.

Comment: to answer your question, i should know that what value are you expect to be shown in your `mTextView_33` textview?

Comment: The mTextView_33 i would like to show me the temperature of the particular city.

Comment: so  as i see in the link 'http://penteli.meteo.gr/stations/larissa/ ', you should use `Element row_33 = rows_33.get(4);` and it's value would be `36.1 c` (if your application stop working by this code it is probably because you have other miss index addressing in your code). as i see if you use  `Element row_33 = rows_33.get(6);` you would address `Dewpoint` that it's value is `17.7 c` that is not `temperature` value.

Comment: Using the command: Element row_33 = rows_33.get(6); 
the application works and temperature gives me the right result like the other fields,while I use Element row_33 = rows_33.get(4);  the application shuts down

Comment: after digging more, finally i found out that the reason for that is that in your  4'th `<tr>` tag (index 3) there is two more `<tr>` tag inside it. so it causes that `temperature` become your 7'th element (index 6) instead  of  5'th element(index 4).